# GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn telerik c# filter

Tags: c#, filter, telerik

there is any way to filter the GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn data while we are input text , i was used the datatable for the data source any solution about filter the data on GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn

i tried use the own property of the GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn such as : FilterDescriptor,FilteringMode,AutoCompleteMode

```html
GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn col = new GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn();
FilterDescriptor filterComboBox = new FilterDescriptor();
col.FilteringMode = GridViewFilteringMode.DisplayMember;
col.DropDownStyle = RadDropDownStyle.DropDown;
col.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to show only list items.
I hope my solution below what you need. Any questions please let me know.

```
    // DataGridView EditControlShowing event
    private void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;

        // Combobox column
        DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl comboBox = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            comboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            comboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
            comboBox.KeyPress += ComboBox_KeyPress; // This function is below
        }
    }

    private void ComboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // Choose only list item
        if (e.KeyChar < 32 || e.KeyChar > 126)
        {
            return;
        }
        string t = ((ComboBox)sender).Text;
        string typedT = t.Substring(0, ((ComboBox)sender).SelectionStart);
        string newT = typedT + e.KeyChar;

        int i = ((ComboBox)sender).FindString(newT);
        if (i == -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for replay , i meant if we have a list of items when i type 'A' just show those items include " A " alphabet such as " Like " on SQL